# Android Chronometer: setUsesChronometer

Tags: android

I am making a basic notification app and just want to integrate a chronometer to it.
I have the basic notification ready.

How to add chronometer using:  setUsesChronometer();

And also how do I use setVibrate() method for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you are creating your notification, you add below lines to add Chronometer data to your notification.

```
        long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()- elapsedTime);

        notification.setUsesChronometer(true);
```

For vibration, you need to define the vibration pattern -

```
.setVibrate(new long[]{500,1000}) //vibrates at 5000 ms and 1 second.
```

Comment: mChronometer.getBase();

GIves me an error saying 
Nonstatic connot be referenced from static context